# How do I read firebase data for the current active user?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to retrieve data the current user has in the real-time database.
Here is the code so far. userId does not seem to be working. I want it to return the name, email, credits, ... that THAT specific user has in the database.

```
function displayUser(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          // User is signed in.
            var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            var r = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId);
            r.on('value', (snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)
    });
        } else {
          // No user is signed in.
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "no user"
        }
      });
    
}
```

Here is my real-time database I am trying to return the name of the one current logged in user.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "7kNMijKyFDVQ6WEAKMoWB5P8t2u1" : {
      "name" : "Joe"
    },
    "N6QVhNbvOZaDGBu23tjLmIbDakA2" : {
      "name" : "Susie"
    },
    "lok19f1PxGh7xaH30qrMH3iKpBI3" : {
      "name" : "Knight"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Firebase does not automatically store user data in it the Realtime Database. If it is stored in there, it's because your applicaiton code stored it there. If that's indeed the case, edit your question to show the JSON of the user data (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: That code seems to match the data at first glance.  If you set a breakpoint on `const data = snapshot.val();` and run in a debugger, does it reach that?